# Changing from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am currently doin an android project that now requires the use of fragments, rather than activities, in one of the fragments, I have a getView method which used Activity methods, and I don't quite know how to change it to be fragment compliant, can anyone help?

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //This method sets what each list view's items contain.
        //Ensure the view isn't null
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.news_rss_item, parent, false);
        }

        //Find the current event to use
        RssItem currentItem = newsItems.get(position);

        //Replace default text with event information
        //Set name
        TextView itemTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemEventName);
        itemTitle.setText(currentItem.getTitle());


        return itemView;
    }
}
```

this is the getView method.

Comment: is the getview from your arrayadapter?

Answer (score 0):

In Fragment, call [getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29) to get activity instance.

I think you need

```
itemView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()....
```

Answer (score 0):

You should attach the `Context` in your `Adapter` like:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public MyAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    ...
}
```

With this you can get your context - `FragmentActivity` - with **mContext** variable and use it in your `Adapter`:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
...
itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_rss_item, null);
```